Finding integral of (-1 * sin(2π/T * t))**(n+1) dt from zero to T/2
I have a problem with finding an integral of a function using Python sympy. I have tried the code below, but it prints the same expression as I had entered.
import sympy as sp

t, w, n = sp.symbols('t T n')
expression = (-1 * sin(2 * pi / T * t))**(n + 1)

integral = sp.integrate(expression, t)

print("The integral of the expression is:")
print(integral)


@Claudio  is 5.0*(-sin(2pit/T))**(n + 1) a correct answer?

@HadeelAbdelJalil : your question was how to make sympy give a better solution than stating back the problem formulation and is answered. If you have further questions I suggest you ask them separately mentioning what makes you doubt that the by sympy provided solution is correct.

Please stop double posting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78467853/sympy-integral-gamma-function

Does this answer your question? Sympy Integral, Gamma Function

As was noted previously, you probably forgot to tell SymPy what you implicitely assume about your variables. Your original code contains issues and it does not even work. My guess is that you implicitely assume that n is a positive integer. When you tell this to SymPy, your integral yields a result.
Here is my version of your code:
import sympy as sp

t, T = sp.symbols('t T', real=True)

# We assume n to be a positive integer value
n = sp.symbols('n', integer=True, positive=True)

expression = (-1 * sp.sin(2 * sp.pi / T * t))**(n + 1)

integral = sp.integrate(expression, t)

print("The integral of the expression is:")
print(integral)

